# Can we use Kibana for Apache Solr not using elasticsearch

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, kibana

How to integrate Kibana with Apache solr instead of using elastic search.

If it cannot be done.

What are the alternatives to Kibana for Solr

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At LucidWorks, we have ported Kibana to work with Solr and released it as open source.

If you want a bundled package, you can download that at http://www.lucidworks.com/lucidworks-silk/.

Our port for Kibana for Solr is bundled with Solr 4.7.0 and can be used as a query engine to build dashboards from indexes within the bundled Solr instance and/or located on other Solr instances.

The source code is available at https://github.com/LucidWorks/banana.

We have also included Solr Output Writer for LogStash with that bundle;  however, you can use any ETL and indexing mechanism to get time series data into Solr. Links to this github repository are available on the LucidWorks link above.

Comment: Thank you for details. What's difference between SiLK and Banana (https://github.com/LucidWorks/banana/)? My understanding SiLK is packaged and good for installations "from scratch", while Banana might be more relevant if a company already has exesting Solr installation and just need to add dashboarding, right? Other differences?

Answer (score 5):

[HUE](http://gethue.com) is an alternative search UI for Solr, while it is not good as Kibana for search at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SiLK for sure but you are better off using the fully integrated dashboards module that comes with Lucidworks Fusion.  Fusion will save you a ton of time and make it easier to focus on the search stuff that matters - like building a recommender engine, creating data-driven user experience, driving data enrichment with entity recognition and integrating with Big Data software like Hadoop.