# Setting up Kibana with an Existing Solr Instance

Tags: solr, kibana, lucidworks

I have an existing Solr instance (4.9) up and running with several cores. I've been trying to set up Kibana for the majority of the day and I can't figure out how to incorporate it with my instance of Solr. I'm running locally on Windows 7 for dev purposes but the production is Linux. I've read through [here](https://github.com/LucidWorks/banana) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364598/can-we-use-kibana-for-apache-solr-not-using-elasticsearch) a few times and I'm not picking up on how to get this done. The banana project seemed like the easiest choice but adding it to the banana/ directory did nothing. I started up [LucidWorks](https://lucidworks.com/solutions/solr/) but wasn't able to figure out how to get my existing cores in here. I have about 1.5TB of data in all of my cores (9 of them) so re-indexing is not an option. 
Can someone provide me with resources or tutorials on how to incorporate Kibana with an existing Solr instance or a tutorial on how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

If banana can fulfill your requirements, it is still the easiest choice. I recently set up banana for one of my Solr 5 cores (even though it was released for a 4.x series as far as I can tell), and also had the initial problem that "nothing happened".

Get it from https://github.com/LucidWorks/banana/ and then follow the instructions in the QUICKSTART file:

> Copy Banana folder to $SOLR_HOME/example/solr-webapp/webapp/
>
> Browse to http://localhost:8983/solr/banana/src/index.html#/dashboard

Perform the copy so that you will have a banana folder in webapp/, do not copy the contents of the banana folder directly in webapp/

Further information on the banana dashboard configuration and its options that I found useful are here: https://docs.lucidworks.com/display/SiLK/Dashboard+Configuration